# BroadcastReciever for SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION registered in manifest not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-sms

Registering an SMS broadcast receiver in the Manifest doesn't seem to work anymore.

I'm aware that Android recently [locked down the manifest broadcast receivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) however the `SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION` appears to be on the [exception list](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions).

My receiver looks like this:

```kotlin
class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action != SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION) return
        val messages = getMessagesFromIntent(intent)
        for (s in messages) {
            Log.i("SmsReceiver", s.displayMessageBody)
            Toast.makeText(context, s.displayMessageBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

And registered in the manifest:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application
        ...
        tools:targetApi="33"
        android:enabled="true">
        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS,android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

As you can see, I've been combining tricks from SO for a while and none have proved fruitful as yet. Hopefully it's something stupid, help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Delete `android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS,android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"`.

There is no permission named `android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS,android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS`. `android:permission` does not take a comma-delimited list. And, you do not need that attribute.

Comment: BROADCAST_SMS is still recommended by AndroidStudio and I also need android:exported="true". Then it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should change android:exported="true"